# Can Any one send me the example of LDAP Server authentication with java example

Tags: java, ldap

either used in apache DS,
openLDAP,
active directory 
or any other server.

Following code I have used.
I have called this servet on submit of login.jsp for authentication.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String SUCCESS = "Success.html";
    final String FAILURE = "Failure.html";
    String strUrl = "login.html";
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);

    boolean b = false;

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
    "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid="+ username +",ou=system");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    try {
    // Create initial context
    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

    // Close the context when we're done
    b = true;
    ctx.close();

    } catch (NamingException e) {
    b = false;
    }finally{
    if(b){
    System.out.print("Success");
    strUrl = SUCCESS;
    }else{
    System.out.print("Failure");
    strUrl = FAILURE;
    }
    }
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(strUrl);
    rd.forward(request, response);

    }
```

Can anyone help me for configure ldap server.

Comment: didnt you found it by googling??

Comment: Actually i found many but , i can get those example and also i can get  with with LDAP server.

Comment: then try it, and if you face any problem then get back here with your tried code..

Answer (score 1):

We have [several JNDI Examples](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/JNDI%20Examples).
-jim

Comment: Thanks...@Jeemster 
you have any other example usong apache DS or open LDAP..?

Comment: AFIK, they will work fine with Apache or openLDAP; except the "Changing the Microsoft Active Directory Password". If not let me know. -jim